# Js-ctypes char readString() makes Mozilla crash

Tags: jsctypes

I am using js-sctypes to connect to a shared library in Linux from Firefox.
I am declaring a function from the library as follows:

```
var read_memory = libc.declare("read_memory", ctypes.default_abi, ctypes.int,
                   ctypes.uint32_t, ctypes.char.ptr, ctypes.int, ctypes.int);
```

In C++ library this function is declared as follows:

```
read_memory(unsigned int address, char *buf, int unit_size, int unit_count)
```

I am calling the `read_memory` function in the following way:

```
var my = new ctypes.char().address();
read_memory(0, my, 4, 1);
st = st + my.readString();
```

And it works fine, but when I am calling the function with greater `unit_size` and `unit_count`, for example `read_memory(0, my, 4, 10)`, the Firefox crashes.

Is it because `ctypes.char` is limited in size, or there is another reason for this fault?
Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and the problem is because of character encoding. In my problem I need to convert them from windows-1250 to utf-8.

I used code below:

```
result = myFunctionToInvoke();
var util = priv.Load("LibToConvert.dll");
var wi12502utf8 = util.declare("win12502utf8", ctypes.default_abi, ctypes.char.ptr, ctypes.char.ptr);
var val = wi12502utf8(result);
result = val.readString();
```

In this code I created my own lib (LibToConvert.dll) in C++ to convert characters.